# Why does Out-File throw an error when the content is a filename?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a filename to a file, and get the error below. Can anyone explain what the issue is and how to fix it?

```
Out-File : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'ARCK-DEK-79457884.bin'.
At C:\Users\DM\Documents\KB\V6.4_Regtest\Get-Cert.ps1:9 char:1
+ out-file -filepath "crtname.txt" -encoding Default $crtf
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Out-File], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

Comment: The problem isn't that the "content" is a file name, the problem is that `Out-File` doesn't accept content at all -- at least not as a nameless parameter. Use either `echo $crtf | out-file`, `set-content`, or `out-file -inputobject $crtf`.

Comment: I used 'out-file -inputobject $crtf' - worked as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: BTW, Out-File appended <CRLF> to the end; is there any way to suppress that?

Comment: I'm going to refer you to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) on that one, although even tab completion would reveal it.